# How do smallest width for layouts work with this example?

Tags: android, android-layout

*I have read the officel documentation but still dosn't understand it!*

I'm playing and experimenting with the smallest-width layouts in Android and it dosn't give any sense to me.

I have created these layouts: `sw-300dp/350dp/360dp/400dp/450dp/500dp/`
But my Galaxy S7 use the `sw-360dp layout`. But `360dp` is far from any of the numbers provedid by `getDisplayMetrics();` or the numbers of the screen I got from GSMArena. So why do Galaxy S7 use `360dp` and not `500dp` since the xdpi is 580dp and closer to 500dp?

**Test Phone:** Samsung Galaxy S7

**Screen Size:** 5.1"

**Resolution:** 1440x 2560 (577 ppi)

From det Logcat I retrived the following screen values of the phone:

```
getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi: 640
getDisplayMetrics().xdpi: 580
getDisplayMetrics().ydpi: 575:
getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels: 1440
```

Comment: The width is 1440 px. How many dp is that? DisplayMetrics will give you the pixel to dp ratio for the device

Comment: @FletcherJohns I don't know how many dp thats is.

Comment: What is getDisplayMetrics().density ?

Comment: @FletcherJohns 640dpi !

Comment: There are 2 fields, density and densityDpi

Comment: @FletcherJohns For my galaxy S7 its 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density of the screen on the S7 is 4.0

That means that there are 4 pixels per dp, therefore the screen is 1440 / 4 = 360dp wide.

I use the following methods frequently:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public static int pxToDp(int px) {
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Comment: Ahaaa! So I just have to divide the width of any screen with it's density number to get the smallest width!

Comment: Almost. The idea of "smallest width" is that layout won't be used on a screen that is less than 360dp wide. For example, try removing that layout and see which one the phone uses then. My guess is it will use the 350dp one.

Comment: Yes it use sw300dp. But is there any standard swxxxdp schemas/sheet that can tell you which numbers are for what screensizes/models or do I have to calculate all that for each layout in different phones?